# calculate kth power of 2

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I was solving a problem and the basic idea to calculate the power of 2 for some k. And then multiply it with 10. Result should be calculated value mod
10^9+7.

Given Constraints 1≤K≤10^9

I am using java language for this. I used 'Math.pow' function but 2^10000000 exceeds its range and I don't want to use 'BigInteger' here. Any other way to calculate such large values.

The actual problem is:

For each valid i, the sign with number i had the integer i written on one side and 10K−i−1 written on the other side.

Now, Marichka is wondering — how many road signs have exactly two distinct decimal digits written on them (on both sides in total)? Since this number may be large, compute it modulo 10^9+7.

I'm using this pow approach, but this is not an efficient way. Any suggestion to solve this problem.

My original Solution:

```
/* package codechef; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
class Codechef
{
 public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = scan.nextInt();
    while(t-->0){
        long k = scan.nextInt();
        long mul=10*(long)Math.pow(2, k-1);
        long ans = mul%1000000007;

        System.out.println(ans);
    }
  }
}
```

After taking some example, I reached that this pow solution works fine for small constraints but not for large.

```
while(t-->0){
        long k = scan.nextInt();
        long mul=10*(long)Math.pow(2, k);
        long ans = mul%1000000007;

        System.out.println(ans);
    }
```

This pow function is exceeding its range. Any good solution to this.

Comment: Only a small hint, since I'm just figuring out how to use that fact myself: 10 ^ 9 + 7 is prime.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, `f(g(x)) mod M` is [the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Properties) as `f(g(x) mod M) mod M`. As exponentiation is just a lot of multiplication, you can just decompose your single exponentiation into many multiplications, and apply modulo at every step. i.e.

```
10 * 2^5 mod 13
```

is the same as

```
10
* 2 mod 13
* 2 mod 13
* 2 mod 13
* 2 mod 13
* 2 mod 13
```

You can compact the loop by not breaking up the exponentiation *so far*; i.e. this would give the same answer, again:

```
10
* 4 mod 13
* 4 mod 13
* 2 mod 13
```

Faruk's recursive solution shows an elegant way to do this.

Comment: Your example `10 * 2^5 mod 1000000007`, well, of course that's the same, as the result `320` is still _much_ lower than `1000000007`. (Not saying that it's not true in the general case, but the example is pretty bad)

Comment: @tobias_k: True, I should have used a lower `M` (I really don't want to unroll a loop that would overflow 1000000007 :D )

Comment: what? Since when is `f(g(x)) mod M == f(g(x) mod M) mod M`. It is not even true for exponentiation. We have `a^b mod M != a^(b mod M) mod M`

Comment: @AndreasH. I oversimplified; but it does hold for the operation OP needs (`(a*b) mod M == (a mod M)*(b mod M) mod M`)

Comment: in the first example 10* 2 mod 13 = 10*2 and after 5 loops its 32*10. What is shorten here. nothing

Comment: Who's talking about "shortening"? Your issue was that `2^10000000` exceeds the range of both `double` and `long int`. This leaves you with two choices: ready-made `BigInteger`, which you explicitly didn't want to use, or using a mathematical trick to make sure the calculation does not overflow, which involves a loop. `10 * 2^5` is `320`, `320 mod 13` is `8`. `10 * 2 % 13` is `7`, `* 2 % 13` is `1`, `* 2 % 13` is `2`, `* 2 % 13` is `4`, `* 2 % 13` is `8` - same result, without ever going over `20` - overflow averted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the idea of dividing the power by 2.

```
long bigmod(long p,long e,long M) {
    if(e==0)
        return 1;
    if(e%2==0) {
        long t=bigmod(p,e/2,M);
        return (t*t)%M;
    }
    return (bigmod(p,e-1,M)*p)%M;
}

while(t-->0){
        long k = scan.nextInt();
        long ans = bigmod(2, k, 1000000007);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
```

You can get details about the idea from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-avoid-overflow-in-modular-multiplication/

Comment: I was thinking it should be possible to compact the loop a bit, but couldn't write it elegantly from head. My answer explains the basics, but this answer would be actually used in production. Very nice.

Comment: Java doesn't have a long long type. Java int is a signed 32-bit type, a long is a signed 64-bit type.

Answer (score -1):

As the size of `long` is 8 bytes and it is `signed` datatype so the range of `long` datatype is `-(2^63) to (2^63 - 1)`. Hence to store `2^100` you have to use another datatype.